# Trying to change a php script from blocking identical ip to blockingidentical ID numbers

Tags: php, scripting

I am very new to PHP and still trying to learn the "ins and outs" to it.(Self-taught) I have a petition website that I had a friend develop a code for, to block identical ip's from signing more than once.

This particular petition is sent to offices with multiple signers that use the same IP, so I am needing to change the code from blocking duplicate IP's to blocking duplicate "GLVAR" numbers the signer provides. I have the database setup, but I just dont know where to exactly change the coding to make this work.

Also, I am trying to send the information the signer submitted to my email address for an extra copy. I know this should be simple, but like I said, I am self teaching and very new, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for your time.

```
<?php
include('database/config.php');
include('database/database.php');

$err = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){        

    $first = addslashes(trim($_POST['first'])); 

    $last = addslashes(trim($_POST['last']));   

    $glvar = addslashes(trim($_POST['glvar']));

    $ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    //echo $ip;

     if(($first!='')&& ($last!='')&& ($glvar!='')){ 

        $database = new Database(HOST, DATEBASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);   

        $allUsers = $database->select('user','ip','*',"ip = '".$ip."'");
        //echo $ip;     

        $checkIp = 0;           
    $checkIp = count($allUsers);    

        $userData = array(              
            'first_name' => $first, 
            'last_name' => $last,               
            'glvar_id' => $glvar,       
            'ip' => $ip,        

        );      

        if(!$checkIp) {         

            $database->insert('user',$userData);        

            header('location:thank-you.html');      

        }    else  $err.='<p style="color:red">Ooops! You have already signed the petition</p>';        

    } else {    

        if($first=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your first name not empty</p>';  

        if($last=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your last name not empty</p>';    

        if($glvar=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your GLVAR ID not empty</p>';    

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I apologize, I dont know what your asking for.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the form that generates the php request - in particular what is the format of GLVAR? How do you ensure it is unique?

Comment: The GLVAR ID number is a ID number provided by the state we are located in for this particular orginization. Each persons ID would be unique in that aspect. I would just need the code to search the database for a duplicate ID and block the submission if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query the database for the `glvar` rather than the IP:

It might look like this depending on what the glvar_id columns look like in the database.

```
$allUsers = $database->select('user','glvar_id','*',"glvar_id = '".$glvar."'");
//echo $ip;

$checkglvar = 0;
$checkglvar = count($allUsers);
```

if you want to mail yourself on success then you will want to configure the php mail function for work and add it here:

```
if(!$checkIp) {

    $database->insert('user',$userData);

    mail("to@me.com", "Subject", "message");

    header('location:thank-you.html');

}
```